# Conditional Formatting applied between two cells in two separate sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to apply some kind of conditional formatting that compares two cells in two separate sheets.  I'd like for the cell in one sheet to turn Green if it matches the value of another sheet.  If it doesn't, then it turns Red.  Is this possible?

*EDIT-It seems like conditional formatting cannot be applied when referencing other sheets. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way. Name a range (cell, say B1) in 'one sheet' to reference the required cell from 'another sheet', then use that cell in 'one sheet' with a CF formula rule of the kind:

```
=A1=B1
```

where A1 is the cell to be formatted.

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciated